# Android Studio render preview error : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have started new a project (blank) in Android Studio . When I preview a layout, render is failed with error "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" . Please help me!

Comment: I found that "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 comes when you are trying to run a class compiled using Java 1.8 compiler into a lower JRE version e.g. JRE 1.7 or JRE 1.6. Simplest way to fix this error is install the latest Java release i.e. Java 8 and run your program." My java JRE is 1.7.0.45

Comment: @KrishnaMeena : Yes, I changed preview with Android 6.0 and issue resolved. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have problem in Android Studio and you have installed Android N, change Android rendering version with older one and the problem will disappear.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.